# Where is executable stored after "go run file.go" command?

Tags: go

Where does go compiler store the executable file after executing following command?

```
$> go run file.go
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the `/tmp` folder, if you're using unix machine.

In the `\Users\SomeUser\AppData\Local\Temp\` if you're on windows.

Comment: Thanks! what is default name of the executable?

Comment: The same as run file. In your case it is `file`.

Answer (score 3):

In Go 1.8 or later, use [os.Executable](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Executable) to see where your executable is located:

```
exePath, err := os.Executable()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Failed to get executable path:", err)
} else {
    fmt.Println("Executable:", exePath)
}
```

`go run myprog.go`

`Executable: /tmp/go-build260998498/command-line-arguments/_obj/exe/myprog`